# statistical distance between Degenerate distribution and any probability distribution

Tags: probability, sampling

In sample-based motion planning, sampling methods would change the cost of path and computation time for the same planning algorithm. I would like to compare different sampling methods.

So, the different stochastic process generates sample points. the task is to identify which stochastic process/distribution is the closest to the target value. 
Wasserstein distance is would be a good option? 
kindly suggest your opinion.

Comment: I guess in this case you would be interested in computing distanced between a degenerate distribution and other such degenerate distributions with the same support.

Comment: individual path cost couldn't be the measure for the whole sampling method. It is a standard practice to run the sample based planner for n times and look for the overall performance.